# What is the meta_query key name for the woo product average rating?

Tags: plugin-development, wp-query, woocommerce-offtopic, meta-query

I am asking about meta_query key name to query the woocommerce all product 5 star average rating in wp_query

I have tried to use these names but not working (_wc_average_rating , average_rating, rating)

```php
$args = array(
 'post_type'   => 'product',
 'posts_per_page' => -1,
 'meta_query'  => array( array(
 'key'     => '_wc_average_rating',
 'value' => '5',
 'compare' => '=',
  )
```

Comment: Are you sure the value is exactly 5, and not 5.0 or 5.00 or something like that? Should be easy to confirm that and the key just by looking in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways of passing meta arguments to the `WP_Query`/`get_posts`, you can check them both in the documentation for WP_Query.

There is a single meta structure, like this

```php
$args = array(
    'meta_key'     => 'color',
    'meta_value'   => 'blue',
    'meta_compare' => '!='
);
```

And a multi meta structure, like this

```php
$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'color',
            'value'   => 'blue',
            'compare' => 'NOT LIKE',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'price',
            'value'   => array( 20, 100 ),
            'type'    => 'numeric',
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
        ),
    ),
);
```

This is all explained in the official documentation for WP_Query, [post meta parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters)

Going by what you're trying to get, you'll need to create it as a meta_query, you're example code is incomplete so I can't recreate an example for this.
What you can do to make sure it works is first check if a product has all those fields, and the values you expect, and then try to get them.
Start with one meta, see that it returns the proper product, then add another one, that way you can target easily the problematic meta.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, woocommerce already has a meta or a a field for rating, but my problem is how can i query this rating meta, I do not know what is the  key name exactly to query it .

Comment: That's what I'm saying in the last few paragraphs. Check what meta exists in a product, then you can see what meta keys you have, you can use `get_post_meta($product_id);` for that.

Comment: Thanks, I got it